# UnboundLocalError: local variable 'b' referenced before assignment

Tags: python

I keep getting this error but I have defined the local variable inside function#Get data checkpoint size. Initially I thought that this error might be because of indentation but that's also not working for me.

```
data_checkpoint_size = cclient.samples.list(meter_name ='checkpoint.size')
        data_checkpoint_length = cclient.samples.list(meter_name ='checkpoint.length')
        data_checkpoint_pause = cclient.samples.list(meter_name ='checkpoint.pause')
        data_cpu= cclient.samples.list(meter_name ='cpu')
        data_incomingbytes = cclient.samples.list(meter_name ='incoming.network.bytes')
        data_outgoingbytes = cclient.samples.list(meter_name ='outgoing.network.bytes')





      def counterVolume(data_cpu, data_incomingbytes, data_outgoingbytes, data_checkpoint_size, data_checkpoint_length, data_checkpoint_pause):
          for each in data_cpu:
            a = each.counter_volume
          for each in data_incomingbytes:
            b = each.counter_volume
          for each in data_outgoingbytes:
            c = each.counter_volume
          for each in data_checkpoint_size:
            d = each.counter_volume
          for each in data_checkpoint_length:
            e = each.counter_volume
          for each in data_checkpoint_pause:
            f = each.counter_volume
          pubnub.publish(channel='channel', message= {'cpu': a, 'incoming_bytes': b, 'outgoing_bytes': c, 'checkpoint_size': y, 'checkpoint_length': x, 'checkpoint_pause': z})


counterVolume(data_cpu, data_incomingbytes, data_outgoingbytes, data_checkpoint_size, data_checkpoint_length, data_checkpoint_pause)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
for each in data_incomingbytes:
   b = each.counter_volume
```

What if `data_incomingbytes` is empty? Then the loop won't run and `b` won't be assigned to. The possibility of that happening is what Python is complaining about. You need to assign to `b` (and all the other variables) whether or not the loop runs.

Comment: you are right I did not think about this possibility.. Thanks a bundle